# Capture click events inside a WPF WebBrowser control showing a PDF document

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, pdf, acrobat

I'm developing a Windows WPF application that uses the default WebBrowser control (System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser) to embed web pages. Using the COM object that underlies the WPF control, I am able to manipulate as needed every HTML document loaded inside the control. Just as an example, here is a snippet of the code I use to get a handle of the COM object:

```
public void HookInputElementForKeyboard()
{
    HTMLDocument htmlDocument = (HTMLDocument)webBrowserControl.Document;
    var inputElements = htmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("input");

    HTMLDocumentEvents_Event documentEvents = (HTMLDocumentEvents_Event) htmlDocument;
    documentEvents.onclick += documentEvents_onclick;
    DeregisterAll();
    foreach (var item in inputElements)
    {
        DispHTMLInputElement inputElement = item as DispHTMLInputElement;
        if (inputElement.type == "text" || inputElement.type == "password" || inputElement.type == "search")
        {
            HTMLButtonElementEvents_Event htmlButtonEvent = inputElement as HTMLButtonElementEvents_Event;
            this.hookedElements.Add(htmlButtonEvent);

            htmlButtonEvent.onclick += InputOnClickHandler;
            htmlButtonEvent.onblur += InputOnBlurHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Where I use dependencies from Microsoft.mshtml.dll.
Here I attach handlers to the events of the DOM elements to be able to manage them in .NET code (onclick and onblur events).

With that object (HTMLDocument) I can overcome almost every limitation of the WPF control.
My problem arises when the WebBrowser control navigates to a PDF document (i.e. the response MIME type is application/pdf). In this case I have to assume that the default Adobe Reader plugin is used to show the PDF (this is how my target machine has to behave). I can still get a handle of the underlying AcroRead ActiveX that is used with the following:

```
private void HookHtmlDocumentOnClick()
{
    var document = (IAcroAXDocShim)WebBrowserControl.Document;

    // Just a test
    var obj = document as AcroPDF;
    obj.OnMessage += obj_OnMessage;

}
```

After I added the proper dependencies to the project (Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll)

But at this point I do not know if there is a way to register for the mouse events happening on the document. All I have to do is to handle the click event on the PDF document.

of course, using the following, does not work. The event does not bubble up to the .NET code level.

```
WebBrowserControl.MouseDown += WebBrowserControl_MouseDown;
```

Does Anybody know if there is a way to hook the IAcroAXDocShim in order to do handle mouse-click events?
Any possible alternative? Should I rather go on a complete different path?
Does using directly the AcroRead ActiveX give me some advantages over the current scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following a different approach. I decided to switch to a different UserControl, instead of the WPF WebBrowser, whenever a PDF content is recognized.
I knew that some classes and API for PDF rendering are available when you develop a Windows Store App, so I applied a solution in order to use those classes in my WPF application.

First I edited the csproj file adding the following tag as a child of `<PropertyGroup>`:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>8.1</TargetPlatformVersion>
```

then a section named "Windows 8.1" should appear in the Add Reference dialog window. I added the only assembly of this section to the references. Some more assemblies may be necessary in order to make the solution work:

- System.IO
- System.Runtime
- System.Runtime.InteropServices
- System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime
- System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime
- System.Threading
- System.Threading.Tasks

Once I had those, I wrote a render method that goes through the pages of the PDF file and creates a png file for each page. Then I added the pages to a StackPanel. At this point, you can manage the Click (or MouseDown) event on the StackPanel as you normally would on any UIElement.
Here is a brief example of the rendering methods:

```
async private void RenderPages(String pdfUrl)
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var responseStream = await client.GetInputStreamAsync(new Uri(pdfUrl));

        InMemoryRandomAccessStream inMemoryStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        using (responseStream)
        {
            await responseStream.AsStreamForRead().CopyToAsync(inMemoryStream.AsStreamForWrite());
        }

        var pdf = await PdfDocument.LoadFromStreamAsync(inMemoryStream);

        if (pdf != null && pdf.PageCount > 0)
        {
            AddPages(pdf);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new CustomException("An exception has been thrown while rendering PDF document pages", e);
    }
}



async public void AddPages(PdfDocument pdfDocument)
{
    PagesStackPanel.Children.Clear();
    if (pdfDocument == null || pdfDocument.PageCount == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid PdfDocument object");
    }

    var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
    StorageFolder rootFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
    var storageItemToDelete = await rootFolder.TryGetItemAsync(Constants.LOCAL_TEMP_PNG_FOLDER);
    if (storageItemToDelete != null)
    {
        await storageItemToDelete.DeleteAsync();
    }

    StorageFolder tempFolder = await rootFolder.CreateFolderAsync(Constants.LOCAL_TEMP_PNG_FOLDER, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

    for (uint i = 0; i < pdfDocument.PageCount; i++)
    {
        logger.Info("Adding PDF page nr. " + i);
        try
        {
            await AppendPage(pdfDocument.GetPage(i), tempFolder);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error("Error while trying to append a page: ", e);
            throw new CustomException("Error while trying to append a page: ", e);
        }
    }
}
```